# weird boolean answer when Comparing two strings in Java

Tags: java

I am encountering a weird problem. I was trying to compare two 128 bits strings and I believe every char of them match each other(and I tested comparing String.chartAt(#) several times) but when I do 
if (String 1== String 2)
..
else
..
It went to else clause. Why is that?

Comment: use String1.equals(String 2)

Comment: Weird things: the number of newbies that don't do the 5 seconds of research required to resolve this issue... But prefer to spend 5 minutes to write up a question here. Then: that strange correlation between : speed of incoming answers vs question being an obvious dup.

Answer (score 0):

When using == for comparison, you are checking if both variables refer to the same object (reference comparision). You should use strings equals() method in order to compare if they are equal in a sense they consist of same characters.

[description of equals method in java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> public boolean equals(Object anObject)
>
> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that
>   represents the same sequence of characters as this object.